# Assign multi instances to lb group

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using terraform in order to assign instances to lb_target_group.

I have 3 servers named: test-1 , test-2 , test-3 - The servers are created from a module & i made an output

Below is the code that is working with a single instance: test-1

My goal is to include all 3 servers

** server output **

```
output "test-1-id" {
  value = module.test-1.tps-vm-instance-id
}
output "test-2-id" {
  value = module.test-2.tps-vm-instance-id
}
output "test-3-id" {
  value = module.test-3.tps-vm-instance-id
}
```

**Working code**

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "test_node_instances_group" {
  name     = "test-node-instances-group"
  port     = 443
  protocol = "HTTPS"
  vpc_id   = module.vpc.vpc-id
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "test_node_instances" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.test_node_instances_group.arn
  target_id        = module.test.test-1-id
  port             = 443
```

**The code that is not working for me**

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "test_node_instances_group" {
  name     = "test-node-instances-group"
  port     = 443
  protocol = "HTTPS"
  vpc_id   = module.vpc.vpc-id
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "test_node_instances" {
  count = 2
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.test_node_instances_group.arn
  target_id        = module.test.test-[count.index]-id
  port             = 443
```

Will appreciate your advice

Comment: What is the definition of `aws_instance.test-1-id`?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing more, I **guess** your problem is with this line (although some error message or other summary of "not working" would be great, otherwise we don't know what the problem is):

```
  target_id        = module.test.test-[count.index]-id
```

This doesn't seem to be a valid Terraform syntax.

Instead what you can do is to define a list or map with the ids to be used here, e.g. something like this (not tested):

```
locals {
 ids_of_instances = [module.test.test-1-id, module.test.test-2-id, module.test.test-3-id]
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
  target_id        = local.ids_of_instances[count.index]
```

Also - not sure why you have `count = 2` there and not `3`?